# Return Elasticsearch slowlogs settings to default

Tags: elasticsearch, logging

I want to be able to set the slowlogs time to 0 for a period, then reset the setting back to the default.
I use

```
curl -X PUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"index.search.slowlog.threshold.query.warn": "0s"}' "<ADDRESS>:9200/index/_settings"
```

to activate slowlogs. which adds

```
"search": {
   "slowlog": {
      "threshold": {
         "query": {
           "warn": "0s"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

to the settings. I can do

```
curl -X PUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"index.search.slowlog.threshold.query.warn": "-1"}' "<ADDRESS>:9200/index/_settings"
```

to deactivate slowlogs, but that leaves the new settings block in place where I want the settings to return to what they were before my meddling.

Is there a way to return the settings to default? (Ideally removing the whole new block so the settings are exactly as they were before.)

Answer (score 3):

You can reset to default by passing `null` as the value of a setting.

```
curl -X PUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -d '{"index.search.slowlog.threshold.query.warn": null}' \
  "<ADDRESS>:9200/index/_settings"
```

Elasticsearch documentation for updating index settings via API
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.12/indices-update-settings.html#reset-index-setting

Answer (score 0):

What you want is not possible, Instead of that you can have a look at https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules-slowlog.html and see what are the default values of slow log settings and then when you want to revert these, just update the log setting with the default values.